# Collapsible menu isn't working - Argument 'SidebarController' is not a function, got undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I'm working on making a collapsible menu with Angular, but it seems to have broken the rest of my webpage! I've isolated it to be somewhere in my `app.js` file, which controls everything. I get the error stated in the title:

`Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'SidebarController' is not a function, got undefined.`

```
'use strict';

(function() {

// Declare app level module which depends on views and components
angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.view1',
  'app.view2',
  'app.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);

//Sidebar toggle
app.controller('SidebarController', function($scope) {

$scope.state = false;

$scope.toggleState = function() {
    $scope.state = !$scope.state;
};

});

app.directive('sidebarDirective', function() {
return {
    link : function(scope, element, attr) {
        scope.$watch(attr.sidebarDirective, function(newVal) {
              if(newVal)
              {
                element.addClass('show');
                return;
              }
              element.removeClass('show');
        });
      }
   };
});

}())
```

And here's the relevant `<div>` that contains the sidebar:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" ng-class="" ng-cloak>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper" ng-controller="SidebarController" class="sidebar" sidebar-directive="state">
      <a id="navigation-toggle" ng-click="toggleState()">MENU</a>
      <ul class="navigation">
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <a href="#/view1">Denon Settings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="navigation-items">
          <a href="#/view2">Light Settings</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

What's going on?

Comment: What is `app` while registering `SidebarController` controller? basically it should be `var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.view1',
  'app.view2',
  'app.version'
])`

Comment: Okay, that was it! I had not properly defined `app` in the first place.

Comment: You could add that as an answer..or you could also delete the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! The problem was that I did not properly define `app`. The declaration should read:

```
// Declare app level module which depends on views and components
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngRoute',
  'app.view1',
  'app.view2',
  'app.version'
]).
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```